# Ui-Bootstrap document click Accordion collapse

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I recently switched to ui-bootstrap for an angular app. With regular bootstrap, I can use the following to collapse an open accordion. What is the equivalent click event with ui-bootstrap?

```
    $(document).on('click',function(){
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a default bootstrap feature. Just add `in` to `collapse` class.

You can use this code below.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-  target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
</button>
<div class="collapse in" id="collapseExample">
     <div class="well">
      asf sdf adsf asdf fd asdf
     </div>
</div>
```

Check this link...
[bootstrap collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example)